# Clojure sort String values - case insensitive

Tags: functional-programming, clojure, clojurescript

I'm trying to sort a map by values (case insensitive). But it seems clojure sort function is case sensitive.
See below example ,

```
cljs.user=> (sort {:1 "A" :2 "Z" :3 "i"})
([:1 "A"] [:2 "Z"] [:3 "i"])

cljs.user=> (reverse (sort {:1 "A" :2 "Z" :3 "i"}))
([:3 "i"] [:2 "Z"] [:1 "A"])
```

Can anyone please suggest me a solutions for this how can I sort in clojure by case-insensitive ?

Comment: Please note that [tag:javascript] has almost nothing to do with [tag:java] and *nothing* to do with [tag:clojure].

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've seen some neat projects done in ClojureScript...

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- - Heh. And yet. :-)

Answer (score 7):

Java provides a case insensitive string comparator:

```clj
(def m {:1 "A" :2 "Z" :3 "i"})
(sort-by val String/CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER m) ;; => ([:1 "A"] [:3 "i"] [:2 "Z"])
```

Comment: this one is nice, but i'm pretty sure that op is using clojuresctipt, so it won't work.

Answer (score 4):

this one would probably work:

```
user> (sort-by (comp clojure.string/lower-case val) {:1 "A" :2 "Z" :3 "i"})
;;=> ([:1 "A"] [:3 "i"] [:2 "Z"])
```

or for `:rank` from op's answer:

```
user> (sort-by (comp clojure.string/lower-case :rank) [{:rank "A"} {:rank "Z"} {:rank "i"}])
;;=> ({:rank "A"} {:rank "i"} {:rank "Z"})
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer for this problem is

```
 cljs.user=> (sort-by :rank #(> (clojure.string/upper-case %1) (clojure.string/upper-case %2))  [{:rank "A"} {:rank "Z"} {:rank "i"}]) 
({:rank "Z"} {:rank "i"} {:rank "A"})
```

Here we are comparing the values one by one after converting them to upper-case.

Comment: Mixing `upper-case` and `capitalize` seems pretty cursed.

Comment: @amalloy updated the solution. didnt realize i wrote it wrong. As it should be comparing after conversion to upper-case. Thanks